# The kernel of a representation is a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

> Let $X$  be a matrix representation.
> Let the kernel of $X$ be defined as $N = {\{g \in G: X(g) = I}\}$. A representation is faithful if it's one to one.
>
> Show that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and find a condition on $N$ equivalent to the representation being faithful.

Proof:

Let $X : G → GL(V)$ be a group representation. Let $g_1 \in N$ and $g \in G$.

Then $$X(g^{-1}g_1g) = X(g^{-1})X(g_1)X(g) = X(g)^{-1}(I)X(g) = X(g)^{-1}X(g) = I.$$

Thus $g^{-1}g_1g \in N$, so $N$ is a  normal subgroup of $G$.

Further, $X$ is faithful if and only if $N$ is the identity subgroup of  $G$.

---

Can someone please verify, or give feedback on, this proof.

Comment: This question is kind of bizarre to me. Your proof is perfectly correct, but a representation $X$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to $GL(V)$, and the kernel of *any* group homomorphism is a normal subgroup of the domain. Of course, this is often proved the way you just did, but I find it unusual that this would come up in a first course in representation theory.

Comment: yes, it seems pretty obvious that the kernel is a normal subgroup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, everything is in working order here. It's the same format to prove that the kernel of *any* homomorphism is a normal subgroup, so I'm a little surprised you didn't just say that the representation $X$ is, among other things, a homomorphism and thus its kernel is a normal subgroup of $G$.

You also have a perfectly good characterization of a faithful representation, that it has a trivial kernel. The non representation-specific version is that *any* homomorphism is injective if and only if its kernel is trivial.

Comment: I guess it's pretty obvious if we mention a matrix representation is a homomorphism, and we know that the kernel of any homomorphism is a normal subgroup. Thanks!

Comment: Sure! One of the joys of algebra, keeping track of the results and mindsets you have at your disposal :)